# Change labels inside Repeater in Real Time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to change a label inside a repeater in real time based on the value of a textbox that is also inside the repeater.

I have tried using JS to solve this but can not access the label nor the textbox inside the repeater.

I have no problem accessing the label or textbox if it's outside the repeater

JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('<%=labelToUpdate.ClientID%>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%=txtInput.ClientID%>').value;
</script>
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInput" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="labelToUpdate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Any help always appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeater controls are inside the ItemTemplate, so you cannot reference them directly. You need to access them by an index.

With your method you could do this

```
document.getElementById('<%= Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("labelTotalCsrPercentage").ClientID %>').innerHTML = 
   document.getElementById('<%= Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("txtInput").ClientID %>').value;
```

Or it becomes easier when using jquery. You can then use `nth-of-type` selector

```
$('#MyRepeater1 span:nth-of-type(2)').html($('#MyRepeater1 span:nth-of-type(2)').prev('input').val());
```

For this you need to wrap the Repeater with an element with a unique ID

```
<span id="MyRepeater1">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    </asp:Repeater>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

`asp:repeater` adds its `id` (and its parent `id`s) *before* item level control `id`s. So use this idea. Place script **after** the repeater.

```
<script>
//language="javascript" is deprecated
//type="text/javascript" is default and cam be omitted
var txts = document.querySelectorAll('input[id$=txtInput]');
for(var i = 0, txt; txt = txts[i]; ++i){
    txt.addEventListener('change', function(){
      document.getElementById(this.id.replace('txtInput', 'labelToUpdate')).innerHTML = this.value;
      });
}
</script>
```

You can also use jQuery if it is easier.